# 3-terminal feedthrough capacitor vs. 4-terminal X2Y capacitor for in-line power filtering

Tags: capacitor, emi-filtering

I know that feedthrough capacitors have excellent noise filtering capabilities by placing their series inductance and resistance also in series with noise and offering a very low impedance to ground. Therefore, I have seen them used in some designs instead of ferrite chip beads, whose filtering performance degrades at higher currents levels due to gradual core saturation.

The X2Y type is commonly praised as the ultimate part by its manufacturers, also as a replacement for feedthru caps, but I fail to see how this can work. [Sources advertising such operation](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/CX0603MRX5R6BB184) place the X2Y in parallel with the line as a noise shunt, and *not in a feedthrough manner*.

It seems possible to "abuse" a X2Y cap as a feedthrough cap: namely by passing the line through its two transverse pads and attaching GND to the two capacitor pads.

Has anyone done/tested this? Will the noise filtering of this be similar to a feedthrough cap ? For the feedthrough cap, as the GND is attached to the transverse pads, there would be less inductance in the shunt path, so I image filtering would be more efficient for the feedthrough cap ?

The reason I find this interesting is because both feedthroughs and X2Y are sort of niche, and one could consolidate the stock by keeping one around if it fulfills the role of the other.

Comment: I have also asked Johanson Dielectric about some info regarding question 1.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: They did reply, but didn't really answer my question. Probably they have no public data on it that they are willing to share. Regarding (1): For a future design I have specced both feedthroughs and two different X2Y configs as power filters after SMPS and will simply compare them in that role. For (2) I use them on a few digital ICs for decoupling. But I don't think that they will be better than regular small caps here as noted above, but I hope that they will keep clock noise better away from the rest of the surrounding when wired as feedthrough.

Comment: thank you for the reply

Comment: "[feedthrough capacitors] instead of ferrite chip beads" -- but these are very different components, a direct substitution isn't possible. Regarding X2Ys in general, I'm unimpressed: the internal structure saves a nH or so, which is easily won back with 2-3 regular chips in parallel (with suitable via pattern). The layout space isn't much different, and the cost is much lower (unless X2Y have gotten much cheaper in the meantime; it's been some years since I looked). Likewise feedthrus, which are most useful for chassis based designs rather than PCB.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've not used any of them myself and can only speculate about their merit for in-line power filtering.. Regarding decoupling though: When you have access to microvias then the X2Y pattern is pretty useful I suppose. Zen 4 CPU use them on the CPU "board" after replacing IDC caps that were used in the previous generation.